# How to remove spurious whitespace in `org-add-note` LOGBOOK drawer

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

When using `org-add-note` (`C-c C-z`) in Org, I'm unable to automatically remove whitespace that is inserted when finalizing the note and the text is filed into the `LOGBOOK` drawer.  `global-whitespace-cleanup-mode` is enabled but does not seem to affect the result.

[image: Logbook note with line breaks]

I was unsuccessful with manually calling `whitespace-cleanup` using the Org Capture finalize hooks:

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-after-finalize-hook (lambda () (whitespace-cleanup)))
```

OR

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook (lambda () (whitespace-cleanup)))
```

How can I capture notes using `org-add-note` and automatically remove the extra whitespace?

### Edit

Since I may be looking at the wrong hooks, I've tried adding `whitespace-cleanup-mode` to `org-log-buffer-setup-hook` via:

```
(add-hook 'org-log-buffer-setup-hook (lambda () (whitespace-cleanup-mode t)))
```

Though, this is running when the capture buffer is created, not when the content is moved into the drawer, so it's too early to be effective.

Comment: `org-add-note` doesn't use `org-capture` (although it seems like it should), which is why the capture hooks aren't getting called

Comment: How could I figure out which hooks are run when `org-add-note` completes?

Comment: Looks like the spaces are being added to align the text.  As when spaces are added to the end of lines or on lines by themselves those spaces are removed.

Comment: Correct. The spaces are inserted to keep alignment.  I've tried disabling this by setting `org-adapt-indentation` to `nil`.  However, there is still a small set of spaces added.  Furthermore, this isn't desired since I _do_ want to keep the indentation level.  Please help if this is the wrong variable to mess with.